# Is there any way to get Instagram direct messages using API or any third party module/tool?

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I have been trying to get direct messages through web hooks. But Facebook graph API only provides mentions, comments and story_insights. I have tried a third party NPM instagram_private_api but it is deprecated since facebook have changed their APIs policy in May/June 2018 and this module was created before it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [new version](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api) of that module, there are a lot of updates since [0.6.8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api)

```
npm i git@github.com:dilame/instagram-private-api.git#0.8.31
```